# Android SimpleOnScaleGestureListener Scale start

Tags: android, gestures

I have a `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` implemented over a `View`, and whenever I put two (and more) fingers on the Screen, It registers that a `Scale gesture` begun. Actually, I want the `scale gesture` to begin when the fingers are moving, not when they are **DOWN** on the screen.

How can I tell the real scaling begun? The `onScaleBegin` and `onScaleEnd` register also that the Scaling begins when the fingers go **DOWN** on the screen, not when they're moving just as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `onScaleBegin` is called when the second finger touches the screen.What you need is to overwrite `onScale` - that fires when you start moving your fingers. You can also keep the initial value of `detector.getScaleFactor` from `onScaleBegin`'s parameter and act when that changes, but that would be more complicated.